# How to manually trigger fsync()?

Tags: performance

I've used libeatmydata to quickly perform `apt-get update`. Now I want to run standard fsync to make sure that everything is written to disk. How can I do it? Preferably a small script / binary, and for bonus points fsync for real even when libeatmydata is pre-loaded

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `sync` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can also press [<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key).

Comment: Where would that magic key be on my MacBook "smalish" keyboard?

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea. But this would be a great question to ask here, if only for future reference.